# Network Session monitoring linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, inode, netlink

I'm using libnetfilter_conntrack to monitor network sessions in c++.
The only thing that is missing is the PID that created the session (socket).

Currently what i'm doing is get the inode of the session from /proc/net/tcp and then go over /proc//fd to search the process that own this socket inode.

This is very inefficient and if the process is very short, i will not get it in time.

Is there a better way of doing this from userspace? 
If not, is possible to build a simple kernel module that will translate inode to pid more efficiently?

Comment: Won't the netstat command help?

Comment: No, i want to get the PID for each events the i receive from libnetfilter_conntrack